# Filter table using dropdown

Tags: javascript, html-table, filtering

I'm making a website here: https://opportunities.sarahlim3.repl.co/discover.html

How can I change the JavaScript functions so that the filter by location dropdown and the filter by category dropdown work together so that table values will show up according to these two conditions if a user clicks on two? The other problem is that internships with categories of computer science and political science also show up when you click the "science" in the dropdown. How can I make it be the exact word?

Here's the code for the page:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
 
<head>
  <title>Table</title>
 
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="discover.css">
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
</head>
 
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="discover.html">Find high school internships</a>
      <a href="resume.html">Resume and CV Template</a>
 
    </div>
  </nav>
 
  <h2>Add a High School Internship Listing</h2>
  <p>*The five fields are required to add (paid internships only)</p>

  <form>
    

<div class="search-box">
  <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" id="searchList" onkeyup="searchFunction()" placeholder="Search by name..."> <a class="search-btn" href="#">
<i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </a>
</div>
      
    <table id="input-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Internship name</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Internship location</th>
          <td><select id="location">
        <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Internship category</th>
          <td> <select id="category">
                <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
            <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
           <option value="Business/Marketing">Business/Marketing</option>
            <option value="Music">Music</option>
            <option value="Art">Art</option>
           <option value="All STEM fields">All STEM fields</option>


        </select></td>
        </tr>
   

        <tr>
          <th>Internship link</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="link" id="link" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th>Internship deadline</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="deadline" id="deadline" required></td>
        </tr>
 
 
        <tr id="btna">
          <td colspan="2"><input type="button" name="button" id="btn" value="Add" onclick="onSubmit()"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>


<select id="mylist" onchange="locationFunction()" class='form-control'>
      <option value="">Filter by location</option>

 <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
</select> 




<select id="categorylist" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
    <option value="">Filter by category</option>

 <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
            <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
           <option value="Business/Marketing">Business/Marketing</option>
            <option value="Music">Music</option>
            <option value="Art">Art</option>
           <option value="All STEM fields">All STEM fields</option>
</select> 

    <table id="show" style="padding:30px; width:90%;" class="internshipInfo">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Internship name</th>
           <th>Internship location</th>
           <th>Internship category</th>
           <th>Internship link</th>
  <th>Internship deadline</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
     </table>
<script>
function searchFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("searchList");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("show");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
    
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      
    }
  }
}
</script>

<script>
function locationFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("show");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
         
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      
      }
      
    }       
  }
}
</script>
     
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, test;
  input = document.getElementById("categorylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("show");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];

    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
   <script>
 
    var list1 = [];
 
   var list2 = [];
 
    var list3 = [];
 
    var list4 = [];
 
    var list5 = [];
 
    var n = 1;
     var x = 0;
 
    function AddRow(data1,data2,data3,data4,data5){
      var AddRown = document.getElementById('show');
      var NewRow = AddRown.insertRow(n);
 
      list1[x] = data1;
 
      list2[x] = data2;
 
      list3[x] = data3;
 
      list4[x] = data4;
 
      list5[x] = data5;
 
    if(list1[x]== "" ||list3[x]== ""||list4[x]== ""||list2[x]== ""||list5[x]==""){
    }else{
       var cel1 = NewRow.insertCell(0);
       var cel2 = NewRow.insertCell(1);
       var cel3 = NewRow.insertCell(2);
       var cel4 = NewRow.insertCell(3);
       var cel5 = NewRow.insertCell(4);
       cel1.innerHTML = list1[x];
 
      cel2.innerHTML = list2[x];
 
      cel3.innerHTML = list3[x];
 
      cel4.innerHTML = list4[x];
       cel5.innerHTML = list5[x];
 
      n++;
 
      x++;
   }
 
    }
 
  async function onPageLoad() {
    let data = await fetch("https://db.neelr.dev/api/6912ef27259834e665455b74d2f5ae43");
    let internships = await data.json()
    Object.values(internships).forEach(v => AddRow(v.name, v.location, v.category,v.link, v.deadline ))
  }
  onPageLoad()
  </script>
 
</body>
 
 
</html>
```

Comment: Include the HTML so that your post provides a good [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I present a naive solution.

- Remove onchange from both the select and Create a new button and set up an onclick listener on that.
- In that listener implementation. You would code combining both
  functions (locationFunction and myFunction)
- This way you will be checking both filters together for both the select elements and on a single click

For instance the current condition

> if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)

would become

`if (txtValue1.toUpperCase() === filter1 && txtValue2.toUpperCase() === filter1)`

P.S You need to combine such that the matching condition would check for filter1 and filter2 together.

Comment: Can you check this?
  var input, filter1, table, tr, td, i, test;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  filter1 = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("show");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    test = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
    if (td) {
      if (td.toUpperCase() === filter1 && test.toUpperCase() === filter1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
         
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      
      }
      
    }

Comment: var input1,filter1,input2,filter2,table,tr,td,i,test;for(input1=document.getElementById("mylist"),input2=document.getElementById("categorylist"),filter1=input1.value.toUpperCase(),filter2=input2.value.toUpperCase(),tr=(table=document.getElementById("show")).getElementsByTagName("tr"),i=0;i<tr.length;i++)td=tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1],test=tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2],td&&(td.toUpperCase()===filter1&&test.toUpperCase()===filter2?tr[i].style.display="":tr[i].style.display="none");

Comment: @SarahLim I hope this answer helps in the right directon.